# Reading and writing arraylist to textfile

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having a problem with reading and writing arraylist to a text file. Specifically with reading. What I'm trying to do is read from a text file and transfer it to an array list. After which i would edit the list and write it back to the text file. I think I go the writing done but not the reading. I've tried reading several similar questions here but cant seem to inject it into my code.

Reading code

```
public void read(List<AddressBook> addToList){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String currentLine= "";
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bank_account.csv"));//file na gusto mo basahin
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(currentLine); // print per line

                for (AddressBook read : addToList) {
                    br.read(read.getName() + read.getAddress() + read.getTelNum() + read.getEmailAdd());
                    addToList.add(read);
                }           }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
            {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here's what I've done with the write

```
public void write(List<AddressBook> addToList) {
        try {
            File file = new File("bank_account.csv"); //file
            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            //FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); 
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for (AddressBook write : addToList) {
                bw.write(write.getName() + "," + write.getAddress() + "," + write.getTelNum() + "," + write.getEmailAdd());
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question? What is the problem/error you are having?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should really be using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). That will clean up a lot of your try/catch/finally code.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(currentLine); // print per line

            for (AddressBook read : addToList) {
                br.read(read.getName() + read.getAddress() + read.getTelNum() + read.getEmailAdd());
                addToList.add(read);
             }
 }
```

I bet in there you will need to do something like:

1. reading each line
2. parsing it (each line is a CSV)
3. creating a new AddressBook object with all that info
4. add it to the collection

The code for that will look like:

```
while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(currentLine); // print per line
        String[] splitted = currentLine.split(",");
        AddressBook address = new AddressBook(splitted[0], splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3]);

        addToList.add(address);
}
```

Of course there are things you will need to check and validate, but that is roughtly it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need read method like this.

```
    public void read() {
        List<AddressBook> addToList =new ArrayList<AddressBook>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String currentLine= "";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bank_account.csv"));//file na gusto mo basahin
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(currentLine); // print per line

//                  for (AddressBook read : addToList) {
                        String[] split =currentLine.split(",");
                        AddressBook read = new AddressBook();
                        read.setName(split[0]);
                        read.setAddress(split[1]);
                        read.setTelNum(split[2]);
                        read.setEmailAdd(split[3]);
//                      br.read(read.getName() + read.getAddress() + read.getTelNum() + read.getEmailAdd());
                        addToList.add(read);
//                  }           
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```